# descriptive statistics of multi level categorical data in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, categorical-data

Below is an example of a df that contains three columns, each with multi-level categorical data. I want to calculate some descriptive statistics across the three columns per level within the column - for instance the number of people per age group in each location and status, including counts, proportions, and standard deviations (which i suppose should actually be a confidence interval here). But I am not sure how to do it in an elegant way. Any advice is really appreciated, thanks so much

```
birth_year = pd.DataFrame(([random.randint(1900,2000) for x in range(50)]), columns = ['year'])

from datetime import date

def age(df,col):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - df[col]
    bins = [18,30,40,50,60,70,120]
    labs = ['-30','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-69','70+']
    group = pd.cut(age, bins, labels = labs)
    return(group)

birth_year.loc[:,'age_bin'] = age(birth_year,'year')


location = pd.DataFrame((Rand(1, 6, 50)), columns = ['location'])

def label_loc (row):
    if row['location'] == 1 :
        return 'england'
    if row['location'] == 2 :
        return 'ireland'
    if row['location'] == 3:
        return 'scotland'
    if row['location']  == 4:
        return 'wales'
    if row['location']  == 5:
        return 'jersey'
    if row['location']  == 6:
        return 'gurnsey'
    return 'Other'

location = location.apply(lambda row: label_loc(row), axis=1)


def Rand(start, end, num):
    out = []
    for x in range(num):
        out.append(random.randint(start, end))
    return out


status = pd.DataFrame((Rand(1, 6, 50)), columns = ['status'])

def label_stat (row):
    if row['status'] == 1 :
        return 'married'
    if row['status'] == 2 :
        return 'divorced'
    if row['status'] == 3:
        return 'single'
    if row['status']  == 4:
        return 'window'
    return 'Other'

status = status.apply(lambda row: label_stat(row), axis=1)


df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(birth_year["age_bin"], status, location)), columns =['year', 'gender', 'ethnicity'])
```

Comment: btw what is `Rand` in this line `location = pd.DataFrame((Rand(1, 6, 50)), columns = ['location'])`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas well spotted sorry - its a function which i have added in to control the spread of the data inputted. thank you for pointing that out

Comment: btw instead of defining a function and then use apply() method you can simply create a dict and map those values

Comment: @AnuragDabas thanks for the tip! would you mind showing me perhaps?

Comment: create a dictionary `d={1: 'england', 2: 'ireland', 3: 'scotland', 4: 'wales', 5: 'jersey', 6: 'gurnsey'}
` finally use `map()` and `fillna()` i.e `location['location']=location['location'].map(d).fillna('Other')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Cimbali/79bbb64d3e18d08eb2c2ade30b2a0b0f) for the example setup slightly rewritten.)</sub>

Let’s take your example:

> the number of people per age group in each location and status

If you had a continuous variable such as `year` you could simply say to `groupby().agg()` which averaged statistics you want:

```
print(df.groupby(['location', 'status'])['year'].agg(['mean', 'std']))

                          mean        std
location status                          
england  Other     1961.000000  16.792856
         divorced  1934.666667  30.270998
         married   1917.000000        NaN
         single    1907.000000        NaN
         window    1962.600000  34.011763
ireland  Other     1982.000000        NaN
         divorced  1949.750000  37.303932
         married   1991.000000        NaN
         single    1986.500000   2.121320
         window    1965.500000   3.535534
jersey   Other     1939.800000  26.204961
         divorced  1984.000000        NaN
         married   1986.000000        NaN
         single    1942.500000  54.447222
scotland Other     1942.666667  12.701706
         divorced  1946.000000  49.497475
         married   1914.000000        NaN
         single    1968.000000        NaN
         window    1933.500000  24.748737
wales    Other     1950.666667  39.526363
         divorced  1978.000000        NaN
         married   1959.000000  52.325902
         single    1929.000000        NaN
         window    1990.000000        NaN
```

With categorical values, you can count them with `value_counts()`, that adds an additional index level (that you can unstack):

```
grouped_age_bin = df.groupby(['location', 'status'])['age_bin']
counts = grouped_age_bin.value_counts().unstack('age_bin')
print(counts)

age_bin            -30  30-39  40-49  50-59  60-69  70+
location status                                        
england  Other       0      1      0      1      0    2
         divorced    0      0      0      1      0    2
         married     0      0      0      0      0    1
         single      0      0      0      0      0    1
         window      0      1      2      1      0    1
ireland  Other       0      1      0      0      0    0
         divorced    1      0      0      0      1    2
         married     1      0      0      0      0    0
         single      0      2      0      0      0    0
         window      0      0      0      2      0    0
jersey   Other       0      0      1      0      1    3
         divorced    0      1      0      0      0    0
         married     0      1      0      0      0    0
         single      0      1      0      0      0    1
scotland Other       0      0      0      0      0    3
         divorced    0      1      0      0      0    1
         married     0      0      0      0      0    1
         single      0      0      0      1      0    0
         window      0      0      0      0      1    1
wales    Other       0      1      0      1      0    1
         divorced    0      0      1      0      0    0
         married     1      0      0      0      0    1
         single      0      0      0      0      0    1
         window      0      1      0      0      0    0
```

If you want the average per category, you can divide by the group sizes, which are `grouped_age_bin.size()`:

```
print(counts.div(grouped_age_bin.size(), axis='index'))

age_bin                 -30  30-39     40-49     50-59  60-69       70+
location status                                                        
england  Other     0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  1.000000
         married   0.500000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.500000
         single    0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  1.000000
         window    0.250000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.25  0.500000
ireland  Other     0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  1.000000
         married   0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  1.000000
         single    0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   1.00  0.000000
         window    0.000000    0.0  0.333333  0.333333   0.00  0.333333
jersey   Other     0.000000    0.0  1.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.000000
         divorced  0.000000    0.0  1.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.000000
         married   0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  1.000000
         single    0.000000    0.0  0.200000  0.400000   0.20  0.200000
         window    0.000000    0.5  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.500000
scotland divorced  0.333333    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.666667
         married   0.000000    0.0  0.333333  0.333333   0.00  0.333333
         single    0.000000    0.5  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.500000
         window    0.000000    0.0  0.500000  0.000000   0.00  0.500000
wales    Other     0.000000    0.5  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.500000
         divorced  0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  1.000000
         married   0.500000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  0.500000
         single    0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.00  1.000000
         window    0.500000    0.0  0.500000  0.000000   0.00  0.000000
```

Now with the population sizes and totals you can compute the confidence intervals. Or you can do simple string aggregation. To have both population sizes and totals I would use `pd.DataFrame.transform` + `pd.Series.combine`, that way you only have to write a lambda that takes the number and total in the categories:

```
print(counts.transform(pd.Series.combine, 'index', grouped_age_bin.size(), lambda num, tot: f'{100 * num / tot:.1f}% (n={num})'))

age_bin                    -30        30-39        40-49         50-59         60-69           70+
location status                                                                                   
england  Other      0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)  50.0% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)   50.0% (n=1)
         divorced   0.0% (n=0)  50.0% (n=1)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)   50.0% (n=1)
         married   33.3% (n=1)   0.0% (n=0)  33.3% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)   33.3% (n=1)
         single     0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=1)
         window     0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=2)
ireland  Other      0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=2)
         divorced   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   50.0% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)   50.0% (n=1)
         married    0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=2)    0.0% (n=0)
         single     0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=1)
         window    33.3% (n=1)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)   66.7% (n=2)
jersey   Other      0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)
         married    0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=1)
         single     0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)
scotland Other      0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)  50.0% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)   50.0% (n=1)
         divorced   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=3)
         married    0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=2)
         single     0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=3)
         window    25.0% (n=1)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   25.0% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)   50.0% (n=2)
wales    Other      0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)  100.0% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)
         divorced  16.7% (n=1)   0.0% (n=0)  33.3% (n=2)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)   50.0% (n=3)
         married    0.0% (n=0)  33.3% (n=1)   0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)    0.0% (n=0)   66.7% (n=2)
         single     0.0% (n=0)   0.0% (n=0)  33.3% (n=1)   33.3% (n=1)    0.0% (n=0)   33.3% (n=1)
```